# How to increase the space between axis and axis label?

Tags: d3.js

I have tried margin which increases the margin between svg and the entire chart which include chart labels. How to increase the space between chart label and axis (See red line below)?

[image]

Thanks for your time viewing this question.

**Update:**

```
<text transform="translate(12,374.6),rotate(-90)" class="y-axis-label y-label" text-anchor="middle" dx="12px">Quantity</text>
```

**Solution:**

Change the `dy` value of text node can increase the space between these two, however, the margin between chart and svg should also be adjusted otherwise, the text is sort of cut off and display partially.

See @timolawl solution below to know how to add note and change its attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
chartWrapper.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'label label--y')
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
  .attr('dx', '.71em')
  .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .text('Sample Label');
```

If that doesn't work, I believe you can also add `.attr('x', fooNumber)` to tweak further .

Comment: Give me a sec. and let me try this out before accept this as an answer. Thanks anyway. `dx` seems does not work.

Comment: Thanks. Change the value of `dy` do change the space between label and axis. However, I still need to increase the margin between chart and svg box otherwise the text will only display partially.

Comment: You should be able to adjust the margins and have everything fit, I believe. For reference, you can check out a Codepen I have for a [d3.js scatterplot](http://codepen.io/timchiang/pen/bpRJJR). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful.